# How can I change the number in the pager string using the jQuery plugin bxSlider?

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow, slide, bxslider

I'm using a plugin called [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com). It's a nice little image slider plugin with a very handy API.

I was wondering if there is a way of changing the number of slides that will be displayed in the pager string.  I'm looking to add a blank slide at the end, but I don't want it to display in the navigation. EG;

I have five slides (four with content and one blank) and I want the pager to display 1/4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the number of slides by adding/removing `li`'s from the content

```
<ul id="slider1">
  <li>Slide one content</li>
  <li>Slide two content</li>
  <li>Slide three content</li>
  <li>And so on...</li>
</ul>
```

Perhaps that is not what you meant though by 'the pager string'? Please clarify

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks for the reply. No, I'm looking to add a blank slide at the end, but I don't want it to display in the navigation. EG;

I have five slides (four with content and one blank) and I want the pager to display 1/4.

Comment: Oh I see.  Yeah, I'd probably try looking for a different plugin that exposes the thumbnail elements so that you can change them manually.  I don't know which will do it but there is a list of 25 jQuery Image Gallery/Slider Tutorials and Plugins at http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/ though it's 2009 so a bit old (but not too much w/jQuery, anyway a start).